# Firebase google authentication with node js

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I would like to add a button '**Login with google**' to my app and I'm trying to do the authentication with firebase in node js. I didn't get any example from firebase official site, where the documentation is given for java script.

please find the code snippet below:

```
const firebaseAdmin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./SAK.json');
const FirebaseAuth = require('firebaseauth');
const authProvider = new FirebaseAuth("API_KEY");
const authToken = FirebaseAuth.initTokenMiddleware(serviceAccount);

firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
    credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

router.get('/loginWithGoogle/', (req,res) => {
    authProvider.loginWithGoogle(authToken, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('err');
    }
    else {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
});
```

The authToken value is null i guess. I'm getting the below error :

TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of null
    at loginWithProviderID (/workspace/sodiumBackend/node_modules/firebaseauth/dist/providers/social-providers.js:22:23)
    at Object.loginWithGoogle (/workspace/sodiumBackend/node_modules/firebaseauth/dist/providers/social-providers.js:57:5)
    at FirebaseAuth.loginWithGoogle (/workspace/sodiumBackend/node_modules/firebaseauth/dist/index.js:61:25)
    at router.get (/workspace/sodiumBackend/src/routes/api/user.js:8:18)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/workspace/sodiumBackend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/workspace/sodiumBackend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/workspace/sodiumBackend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/workspace/sodiumBackend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi,
First of all please check up the documentations for 'Manage Users' in firebase Admin.**

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

Notice the firebase createUser method

```
    admin.auth().createUser({
  email: 'user@example.com',
  emailVerified: false,
  phoneNumber: '+11234567890',
  password: 'secretPassword',
  displayName: 'John Doe',
  photoURL: 'http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png',
  disabled: false
})
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
  });
```

> "By default, Firebase Authentication will generate a random uid for the new user."

After the user was created you can create a token for it

```
var myTokenToSave;
   admin
        .auth()
        .createCustomToken(userRecord.uid)
        .then(function(customToken) {
          myTokenToSave = customToken;
        });
```

**Then eventually authenticate it**

```
 admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
  .then(function(decodedToken) {
    let uid = decodedToken.uid;
    // ...
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle error
  });
```

Hopefully this make sense, the code placement and usage depends on your implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I believe this example is for authentication using  JSON Web Tokens (JWTs).
I would like to authenticate with google account.